# Extj 4 controller this.control listeners debounce?

Tags: extjs4.2

How can I debounce listeners specified inside of controller using

```
this.control
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the sample from the docs, you could use Ext.Function.defer() inside your

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
     init: function() {
         this.control({
             'useredit button[action=save]': {
                 click: function() {
                    //delay function call for a couple of seconds
                    Ext.Function.defer(this.updateUser, 2000, this);
                }
             }
         });
     },

     updateUser: function(button) {
         console.log('clicked the Save button');
     }
 });
```

Comment: Debouncing means that method will be executed no more than once in the specified timeout so Ext.Function.defer is not appropriate.
But the example can be easy adapted to achieve my scope .

Comment: But each click will gets it's own timeout wont it?

Comment: Yes but I need only one handler to be executed.

Comment: How about using the addListener approach where you can pass in a 'single:true' config option - http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Observable-method-addListener

Comment: I need just to replace Ext.Function.defer in your code with Ext.Function.createBuffered.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
     init: function() {
         this.control({
             'useredit button[action=save]': {
                 click: {
                       buffer:2000,
                       fn:this.updateUser
                 }
                }
             }
         });
     },

     updateUser: function(button) {
         console.log('clicked the Save button');
     }
 });
```